# Migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL. Search by bitwise AND. Operator does not exist: bytea & integer

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to move a database from **MySQL 5.5.62** to **PostgreSQL 15.1**.
I used ready-made software that performed this migration.

I have a problem with one SQL command and I can't find the answer to what it is.

In MySQL I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `crm_pew` (
  `id` int(16) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pew` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Then I execute the SQL command:

```
SELECT p.* FROM crm_pew p WHERE (p.pew & 4>0);
```

I get the result. Everything works.

After converting the table to PostgreSQL, the table looks like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE crm_pew_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "public"."crm_pew" (
    "id" bigint DEFAULT nextval('crm_pew_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "pew" bytea,
    CONSTRAINT "PRIMARY01144" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (oids = false);
```

I execute the same SQL command:

```
SELECT p.* FROM crm_pew p WHERE (p.pew & 4>0);
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea & integer
LINE 1: SELECT p.* FROM crm_pew p WHERE (p.pew & 4>0)
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I checked that PostgreSQL has bitwise operators so there shouldn't be a problem.

Maybe a table in PosgreSQL should be of a different type than **bytea**?
I've seen other users get around this using various conversions. I don't want to believe that there are no simple solutions for this case in the latest PostgreSQL.

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's better to use `bigint generated by default as identity` instead of serial (or bigserial)

Comment: It's unclear to me what gets stored in the `pew` column. But if you want to use bitwise operators, you maybe want `bit(16)` instead of `bytea`.

Comment: Good question. MySQL stores the value there in the format `UNHEX('323731')` and the conversion changed it to `\x323731`

In this particular case, the value could be written as an integer. However, I don't know how 50 other places in the system will behave. Analysis and possible refactoring can take a lot of time. For this I would like to keep only the backward compatibility of this data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'd say that's an answer.

Comment: I did a more detailed analysis. The varbinary field in MySQL is used in this and other cases in the form of a flag that can take several values, e.g. the sum of the values 2+8 where 2 means an unread note and 8 means a high priority.

I currently have this SQL command matching PostgreSQL that returns the correct data:

```SELECT p.* FROM crm_pew p WHERE (encode(p.pew, 'escape')::int::bit(16) & 4::bit(16))::int > 0;```

Unfortunately, it is quite complicated, and it seems that it can be done better.